# Realtime graph gui plot by wxpthon and matplotlib

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, wxpython, real-time

I am a 3rd-year student in the electrical department. I am learning about `LoRa communication and the sensor` will send me back the data. I want a simple example of real-time graph plotting by `wxpython` and `matplotlib`. And should be imported by using notepad. I tried to combine all the stuff that I have searched for but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: import data from notepad to python pandas and plot the graph. for real time data plotting you can create a pipeline.

Comment: Bad news: You can write such operations in a lower-level language (** C**). Some friends may recommend a module, but how much is the performance of the module written for general use? I think it's `ctypes` from your starting point. With Python, you can't trade in microseconds intervals. Remember: **communication is always faster than processing**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can receive the data and save in the notepad. The step that i want to know is how to draw a live graph using wxpython and matplotlib. I already have the data in the notepad. Sorry for the grammar.